# (Twitter4J API) -- Not retrieving more than 3235 Tweets

Tags: java, twitter, arraylist, pagination, twitter4j

I am having issues with the Twitter4J API.  I have programmed my program to get tweets from a user account and it does it beautifully, until it reaches 3235 Tweets and breaks.  I do not understand why it stops when it reaches this specific number but I need to retrieve around 9000~ tweets so I am not sure how to fix this.  I am using Pagination to retrieve them.

Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: What error are you getting in the log?

Comment: no errors, it just goes from retrieving tweets from 2014 to retrieving the most recent tweets 2016? and the array list size never changes from 3235. its as if its stuck in a loop or somethings happened cause it continues to run.

Comment: Haven't been on Twitter for a while, maybe there weren't any tweets in 2015?

Comment: nah it gets the tweets all the way back to like october 2014, then decides to cut out when the array list reaches size 3235? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.
From the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/things-every-developer-should-know):

> Clients may access a theoretical maximum of 3,200 statuses via the page and count parameters for the user_timeline REST API methods. Other timeline methods have a theoretical maximum of 800 statuses. Requests for more than the limit will result in a reply with a status code of 200 and an empty result in the format requested. Twitter still maintains a database of all the tweets sent by a user. However, to ensure performance, this limit is in place on the API calls.

So, You can't get more than around 3200 tweets with that method, that's why you are getting 3235.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! thats helped me a lot and cleared up a lot of info! I would 'like' the answer, but I don't have a big enough rep for that :( sorry.

Comment: @JohnLewis: You can accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)